# Detect and handle needing to login for wifi

Tags: android, httpclient, wifi

I'm using `HttpClient` 4.1 in an Android app and trying to make it smart about having my app's API requests intercepted by one of those "you need to login or pay for wifi" screens.

I want to pop up a webview allowing the user to login.

I've been trying to intercept the redirect in httpClient, but I am unsuccessful.

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
this.client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params);

((DefaultHttpClient) this.client).setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
    public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
        boolean isRedirect = Boolean.FALSE;
        try {
            isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to run isRedirected", e);
        }
        if (!isRedirect) {
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                throw new WifiLoginNeeded();
                // The "real implementation" should return true here..
            }
        } else {
            throw new WifiLoginNeeded();
        }

        return isRedirect;
    }
});
```

And then in my activity:

```
try {
    response = httpClient.get(url);
} catch (WifiLoginNeeded e){
    showWifiLoginScreen();
}
```

where the show wifi screen does this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://our-site.com/wifi-login");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

The thinking is this:

- My API will never redirect legitimately
- So I configure HttpClient to throw my special RuntimeException when it's redirected
- Catch that exception in activity code and pop a Webview to get them directed to the login screen
- Once they login, wifi-login congratulates them on a job well done and prompts them back into the app

The thing is, I never get that WifiLoginNeeded exception. What is the preferred way to accomplish this with Android?

Comment: First, make sure your http server returns the correct httpReponse (301 or 302).

Comment: The thing is, it's not my server doing the redirect. It's one of those WiFi access points that points everything to their "Log in to our expensive WiFi" pages. So I need to catch every case we can think of for redirected HTTP calls.

Comment: It may not even be the type of redirect you expect - also make sure the codes you expect are being generated.  The access point does not have to return the particular HTTP code you expect and it may happily send a [200] indicating all is fine while directing you to their access point login screens.

You may want to store the ip address of your site and compare that to the ip address returned by the latest http request.  If they are different, then call up the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

As a more general case: You can include something in your public API like a “Hello World” or “Ping” message.

```
    GET http://api.example.com/1.0/ping HTTP/1.1
    Accepts: text/json

    Content-Type: text/json
    { ping: "ok", currentAPIVersion: 1.1, minAPIVersion: 1.0 }
```

Attempt to connect and “ping” your server. If the response is not returned in the format you expect then, toss the same URL up as an Intent for the user to deal with the results using their web browser of choice.

This would also handle: corporate proxies (“company XYZ forbids you!”), and incompatible changes in your own API in future (“sorry, we no longer support that 12-year-old version of the API. Please download an update there.”)

Answer (score -1):

Try this small solution it will help

```
   public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
            Boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
            return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check the below code. It may be useful to you to check what kind of Connections you are using.

```
WifiManager lWifiManager = (WifiManager) OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager lTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

////////////////////////////
// if we have a fast connection (wifi or 3g)
if( (lWifiManager.isWifiEnabled() && lWifiManager.getConnectionInfo() != null && lWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress() != 0) ||
    ( (lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS ||

    /* icky... using literals to make backwards compatible with 1.5 and 1.6 */      
    lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == 9 /*HSUPA*/  ||
    lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == 10 /*HSPA*/  ||
    lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == 8 /*HSDPA*/  ||
    lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == 5 /*EVDO_0*/  ||
    lTelephonyManager.getNetworkType() == 6 /*EVDO A*/) 

    && lTelephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED) 
    ){
        //Do some thing here
}
```

Comment: This requires extra permissions, which I would like to avoid if possible. If you're already using the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission then this is a good way to go I think.